How do I use a Delphi runtime package in several projects using Rad Studio 11
I have a Delphi runtime package containing some complex calculations in several units.
I want to use that package in a dozen separate projects.  The package compiles without problems.  The applications cannot compile when they reference the package or units within it
The message is:

F2063 Could not compile used unit 'astro.Celest' at line 6 (6,10)

What is that "one simple trick" that makes this possible (and is never mentioned in the Embarcadero documentation)?
I cannot use the "link with runtime packages" option (BPL files), the packages must all be incorporated into the EXE file, so the applications can be stand-alone files.
I have the correct package name in the Project Option->Packages->Runtime Packages.
I have the Search Path set to include the folder where the Package DCU files are created.
The Package compile does not create DCP file, although the selection dialog for the project seems to call for one.  Am I missing some option here?

"The Package compile does not create DCP file" - it should be. Are you looking only in your project folder? Did you check the %PUBLIC%\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\22.0\DCP folder?

I cannot use the "link with runtime packages" option (BPL files) makes no sense, as your question is about using a runtime package. In order to use your own runtime package, you have to enable the standard Delphi runtime packages as well. If you're insisting on everything being in one executable, then your code is not in a runtime package, because a runtime package by definition is contained in a BPL file (that's what a package is, precisely). Can you first sort out your question so that you know what you're asking, and then [edit] to correct your terminology and question accordingly?

A slight correction to my previous comment - you are required to use the standard runtime packages if you create objects in your package that are to be passed back and forth to the main application. This is because you need to use a shared memory manager, which is included in the RTL BPL package. It also applies if your package is creating components that will be shared with the main app, for the same reason.

If you want to have a single executable, don't use a package and instead compile the code directly into your executable

Remy Lebeau, thank you for that comment.  I was looking for the BPI and DCP files in the wrong place.

Ken White, thank you for your response.  My intention is to have a precompiled package which can be used in a dozen applications without including the source code from the package in the application.    This is the practice of a third-party vendor who supplied another package for these applications.  I simply did not understand how they did it.  They used BPI and DCP files compiled from their source codes.

What I am looking for is and answer to the same question that has been asked at least 80 times in this and other forums.

If you want to distribute your component package without showing your code, than you need to compile your pas files to all supported platforms, Delphi versions, maybe also for Debug and Release option sets, and then distribute resulting DCU files. Also do not forget about RES files and OBJ if you are using some C++ code. Distribution of BPL, DCP and friends is only necessary when users want to use your code with runtime packages enabled.
After all of that, the most important task will be to correctly setup IDE paths to all compiled files, because Delphi 11 will not work with DCU files from Delphi 10.4 and vice versa.

Thanks to the other correspondents who also posted the key information about the search path.
I received a complete answer from Embarcadero Technical Support, which is quoted here:

The key is making the associated package binary .dcu(s) available on the library path. You can also just copy the .dcu(s) into a project folder to allow that project to find the units.
You must provide .bpls to developers only if you are sharing design-time packages. The target developer can install a binary design-time package .bpl using Component | Install Packages to allow the components to be made available on their Rad Studio [Component] Palette.
But for runtime packages, you do not technically need to distribute the .bpl, unless you would like to give the developer the option of linking with runtime packages. If so, you must also provide the .dcp.

The default location for package object code in a windows system is:
C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\22.0\Dcp
The unit object code for the package is placed in:
\Win32\Release
